# How do I define QTDIR on Azure pipelines without using the vsproj.user file?

Tags: visual-studio, qt, azure-pipelines

I am building a Visual Studio project with Qt on Azure Pipelines. When the QTDIR is defined on the vsproj.user file, which I just learnt should not be included in the repository, it builds the project with no problems. But because the vsproj.user file should not be in the repo; it means there's nothing defining the QTDIR for when the project is built. I tried to set it as an environment variable, but it doesn't work.

I have Qt installed onto the agent used for the build.

Comment: You could move the definition into the vcxproj file. But there is a reason why it's in the user file, as the path is machine (e.g. user) dependent. I'm not familiar with azure pipelines, but I suggest using an environment variable, and put something like this in the vcxproj: `<PropertyGroup Label="UserMacros"><QTDIR>$(QTDIR_ENV_VARIABLE)</QTDIR></PropertyGroup>`

Comment: Thank you. With Azure pipelines the build is ran on an agent thats installed onto an on premise server. So while developers can set up their own vcproj.user files when they checkout the repo an build on their own machines, i need to be able to build the project on the agent. so my question now is, if I put the variable in the vcproj file, can that be overwritten by the vcproj.user file?

Comment: My approach would involve environment variables. And this is what I don't know about Azure Pipelines, can you specify your own env variables there? otherwise my approach would not work, and you need a different solution...

Comment: Well I had tried that previously and it hadnt worked. I first set the QTDIR as a system variable that could be picked up by the agent but that didnt work. Yesterday I tried to do this directly on the pipeline. I set the pipeline variable to QTDIR = $(Agent.ToolsDirectory)\Qt\5.15.2\msvc2019_64 where $(Agent.ToolsDirectory) is the predefined variable to the tool directory on the agent. But it didnt work. what did work was removing the macro and swapping it with C:\Agent\_work\_tool\Qt\5.15.2\msvc2019_64. I wonder why it doesnt work with the predefined variable.

Comment: I still need a solution, this is just a temporally fix, for ci/cd i need the pipeline to be able to choose the tool directory depending on the agent it is running on, not one i set it myself.